# Loading External SWF w/ Stage reference in class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm unable to load forces.swf (assume I can't edit it, as I don't have the source code) through an external swf, due to Stage reference in the base class.

How would I go about loading it (and any other possible SWF) without errors being thrown?

Here is a link to the problem I am trying to fix:

http://www.mediafire.com/?9d9qay8a6xj7836

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the loaded SWF's and want them to use the stage, first they need to be added on stage ( not like the default SWF is appearing with a stage ).

so you need to use something like this:

```
public function YOURCLASS()
{
    // at this point if the swf is externally loaded, it is only in the memory
    // but not on stage. you can "trace ( stage )" it will give you NULL

    // you need to listen to the event when the object was added on stage.
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);
}

private function handleAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);
    // now the object is added on the stage, and you can refer the stage parameter
    // "trace ( stage )" it will give you [Stage]
}
```

hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Theoreticaly it should be possible like this:

from SWF you need to create a SWC file ( this is the theoretical part of solution )

then you have a NewClass which extends the Constructor class and you're not calling the super ();

...still i do not know what are the chanses to create SWC from SWF...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the loaded swf (theoretically) so I need a way to attach it still.

Comment: updated a theoretical version of the solution. Normaly when the swf is loaded the constructor class is beeing called right away.